# how to populate model list using linq in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I am working on asp.net core application. I have following linq query which is being used to fill a model. This model has a property qtryregions which is a list. How can I fill it in one query.

```
public JsonResult PODetailsList(int id)
    {
        List<PODetailsFull> Products;
        Products =
        (from d in db.PODetails
         join p in db.Products on d.ProductID equals p.ProductID
         where d.POID == id
         select new PODetailsFull
         {
             PODetailID = d.PODetailID,              

             //QtyRegion = new List<string>() { Region.Region + " " + POAllocation.Allocate != null ? POAllocation.Allocate.ToString() : "" },                 
             Sku = p.Sku,
             Cntnr20 = p.Cntnr20 ?? 0,
             Cntnr40 = p.Cntnr40 ?? 0,
             Cntnr40HQ = p.Cntnr40HQ ?? 0,
         }).ToList();


        foreach (var product in Products)
        {
            var result = (from POAllocation in db.POAllocations.Where(p => p.PODetailID == product.PODetailID)
                          join regions in db.Regions on POAllocation.RegionID equals regions.RegionID 
                          select  regions.Region + " " + POAllocation.Allocate ?? ""
        ).ToList();

            product.QtyRegion = result;
        }

        return Json(new { data = Products }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I don't want to use above foreach and want to populate product.Qtyregion in first linq query.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
Products = (
    from d in db.PODetails
    join p in db.Products on d.ProductID equals p.ProductID
    where d.POID == id
    select new PODetailsFull
    {
        PODetailID = d.PODetailID,

        //QtyRegion = new List<string>() { Region.Region + " " + POAllocation.Allocate != null ? POAllocation.Allocate.ToString() : "" },                 
        Sku = p.Sku,
        Cntnr20 = p.Cntnr20 ?? 0,
        Cntnr40 = p.Cntnr40 ?? 0,
        Cntnr40HQ = p.Cntnr40HQ ?? 0,
        QtyRegion = (
            from POAllocation in db.POAllocations.Where(p => p.PODetailID == d.PODetailID)
            join regions in db.Regions on POAllocation.RegionID equals regions.RegionID
            select regions.Region + " " + POAllocation.Allocate ?? "").ToList(),
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: this is causing exception.

Comment: @AsifHameed - You then need to pull your records into memory and do the final query there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Group By to avoid N+1 queries issue:

```
Products = (
from d in db.PODetails
join p in db.Products on d.ProductID equals p.ProductID
join palloc in db.POAllocations on d.PODetailID equals palloc.PODetailID
group by new { 
    PODetailID = d.PODetailID,         
    Sku = p.Sku,
    Cntnr20 = p.Cntnr20,
    Cntnr40 = p.Cntnr40,
    Cntnr40HQ = p.Cntnr40HQ }
into grp
where grp.Key.POID == id
select new PODetailsFull
{
    PODetailID = grp.Key.PODetailID,

    QtyRegion = grp,                 
    Sku = grp.Key.Sku,
    Cntnr20 = grp.Key.Cntnr20 ?? 0,
    Cntnr40 = grp.Key.Cntnr40 ?? 0,
    Cntnr40HQ = grp.Key.Cntnr40HQ ?? 0
}).ToList();
```